# How to find ssh keys generated during install

Tags: ssh, 20.04

During the install process of Ubuntu 20.04, I saw it display either a private or public SSH key on the screen (or both) for my admin user.

After the install, how do I find the public/private key files?

(I don't think it matters, but I'm running on a virtual image on Virtual Box.  I'm able to logon and run commands.)

Comment: The system ssh keys should be located at `/etc/ssh/`.  For local user it is `/home/user/.ssh/`

Comment: @Terrance This looks like an answer to me. Consider adding a bit more details and convert the comment to an answer. :)

Comment: To start with, which version of Linux have you installed  (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, et al.) , and which release number?  Different releases have different tools for us to recommend. Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our channel to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]

Comment: @Terrance - first part seems to be what I was looking for.  I didn't have a .ssh directory in my /home/user yet.

Comment: I could write up an answer later, but the `/home/user/.ssh/` should be created after you run `ssh-keygen` from a terminal window as your logged in user.